# Getting a url of an image nested in a Repeater asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I am trying to get the imageurl of a image that is nested in a repeater. But i dont know what i am doing wrong, i always get a null result. Here is what i have been trying so far

this is the code behind.

```
    public partial class CreateSession : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ImagesForSession img = new ImagesForSession();
    WordForSession wrd = new WordForSession();
    RolesForSession rol = new RolesForSession();
    CreateSes newSes = new CreateSes();
    ManyToMany mToM = new ManyToMany();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        repImagesOnSes.DataSource = img.GetAllImages();
        repImagesOnSes.DataBind();

        repWordsOnSes.DataSource = wrd.GetAllWords();
        repWordsOnSes.DataBind();

        repRolesOnSes.DataSource = rol.GetAllRoles();
        repRolesOnSes.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnCreateSession_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        newSes.CreateNewSession(userID, true, txtSesName.Text);

        //var checkBox = repImagesOnSes.FindControl("imgCheckBox") as CheckBox;
        //var imgControl = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)repImagesOnSes.FindControl("imgForSession");
        //var imgUrl = imgControl.DescriptionUrl;
        //var imgID = img.GetImageId(imgUrl);

        //mToM.AddImagesToSession(newSes.GetNewestSession(userID), imgID);


        foreach (RepeaterItem i in repImagesOnSes.Items)
        {
            CheckBox chk = i.FindControl("imgCheckBox") as CheckBox;

            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                var image = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)i.FindControl("imgForSession");
                var imgUrl = image.ImageUrl;
                var imgID = img.GetImageId(imgUrl);

                mToM.AddImagesToSession(newSes.GetNewestSession(userID), imgID);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

and here is the html

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repImagesOnSes" runat="server" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                                <asp:Image ID="imgForSession" CssClass="img-responsive" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Images/{0}", Eval("FileName")) %>' Height="150px" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="padding-top: 65px;">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="imgCheckBox" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

i have tried to make a hidden field in the repeater item but i cant seem to get that to work either. Hope some of you can help, thanks!

Comment: When do you perform the code behind you are showing? Is the Item data bound at that moment?

Comment: Hey Frank. I my page load i give the datasource and the databind it.

Comment: Could you paste the complete code behind source?

Comment: Yes just a sec it will be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looping through each item of the repeater to determine if the checkbox is checked? You should be finding the control within the repeater item. The following code snippet should help.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem ri in repImagesOnSes.Items)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)ri.FindControl("imgCheckBox");

    if (chk.Checked)
    {
        Image imgControl = (Image)ri.FindControl("imgForSession");
        var imgUrl = imgControl.ImageUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Steve. Right now the problem is already at the imgUrl variable. It says that the value is null when it tries to get the url from the image. But i will need to use this foreach loop when i want to check wich boxes is checked. so thanks for that ! :)

Comment: I updated the code snippet which may help you. I put the find image control within the if checked because you weren't doing anything with it before then. The image URL is null because you are trying to get it from repImagesOnSes where you should be retrieving it from the repeater item.

Comment: for some reason it is still nor adding anything to the database. I have tried what you suggested and have posted it above

Comment: You are declaring your variable as "var image". Trying declare it as Image type like so "Image image"

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your data binding in a !IsPostBack because you're clearing your selection.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack) 
    {
        repImagesOnSes.DataSource = img.GetAllImages();
        repImagesOnSes.DataBind();

        repWordsOnSes.DataSource = wrd.GetAllWords();
        repWordsOnSes.DataBind();

        repRolesOnSes.DataSource = rol.GetAllRoles();
        repRolesOnSes.DataBind();
    }
}
```